# A word or phrase meaning "training and financing him to become"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

A word or phrase meaning "training and financing him to become"?

The only thing I can think of is "build someone up into", but I am not sure it has exactly the intended meaning.

> The company built him up to be a very good CEO.

> The company trained and financed him up to be a very good CEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the verb 'foster' comes to mind, especially if there was a lot of work going into it. A more financially-connotated word you might consider would be 'sponsored'.

That being said, I think your original usage is also fine.